# eclipselink with join and pagination

Tags: mysql, eclipselink, left-join, limit

Currently i am stuck in generating the query via eclipselink for the following relation schema.

Manager can have zero or more employees.(Manager can exist without any employee)

Employee will belong to exactly one manager.(Employee is always mapped to a manager)

```
public class Manager {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private List<Employee> employee;

    private String department;
}

public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="managerId")
    private Manager manager;

    private String status;
}
```

How can i form the left outer join query in eclipselink containing where conditions on either Manager or Employee or both?

eg:

```
SELECT m.id FROM Manager m LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee e ON m.id = e.managerId
WHERE e.id is null or m.department like 'Dev%' AND e.status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY m.id
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

JPQL query is almost the same. You are just not working with tables but with entities:

```
SELECT m FROM Manager m
  LEFT JOIN m.employee e
```

ON condition is already defined in mapping annotation so it's skipped. You can also use 'LEFT JOIN FETCH' to fetch objects trough lazy relationships.
also check https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#LEFT_JOIN

You can specify JPQL query as named query in your enity:

```
@Entity
...
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(
        name="findAllEmployeesOrderById",
        query="SELECT e FROM Employee e order by e.id"
),
@NamedQuery(
        name="findAllEmployeesJoinAddressPhones",
        query="SELECT e FROM Employee e",
        hints={
                @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.FETCH, value="e.address"),
                @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.FETCH,
                           value="e.phoneNumbers")
        }
)
})
...
public class MyEntity { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to make it work with Expressions using anyOfAllowingNull